# How angularjs resource post data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, restful-architecture

Im working with a simple service, posting some data. At the moment I have a service like this:

```
sitekServices.factory('Books', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('books/:id.json', {id:'@id'});
  }]
);
```

In the code I build an object like this.

> $scope.book = Books.get({id:0})

Which builds for me an empty object with some default values. In the application I fill the rest of the object to get something like this:

```
$scope.book =
{
  payment_method: 'Cash',
  provider: 'Acme',
  detail: [{isbn:'foo', price:123}]
}
```

But when I post the data with

> $scope.book.$save()

The data received in the server (rails app) is in the form of:

```
{
  :payment_method => 'Cash',
  :provider => 'Acme'
  :detail => [{:isbn => 'foo', :price => 123}]
  :book => {
    :payment_method => 'Cash',
    :provider => 'Acme'
  }
}
```

Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: Try Books.save($scope.book);

Comment: What you see in Rails might be different from what you see in the actual request. Check out Chrome's Network tab to confirm your request does indeed contain zombie `book` sub-object.